# TFS Database Deployment in Sandbox environment

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a Team Solution which includes the database and dataserver projects – these are currently set to compile and create deployment scripts.  This can take an age so would probably be worth setting them to build & deploy only when needed.

Does anyone have any views on this either way; is there a best practice approach or is it simply solution specific??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience I would go for the latter 'build and deploy when required'...

Comment: Thanks - I assumed this was the way to go, just wondered if there was any underlying advantages to not doing it this ad-hoc way. I'll stick with what i'm doing, thanks!